# Adding a dynamic chapter number to the titlebar of the detail view in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

This part of my app drills from the book overview to the chapter

[image]

[image]

I need it to display the chapter number next to "Chapter"

Here is my current code

#### ProverbContent

```
public class ProverbContent {

    public static List<ProverbItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<ProverbItem>();

    public static Map<String, ProverbItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, ProverbItem>();

    static {

        addItem(new ProverbItem("1", "Chapter 1",
            "1 The proverbs of Solomon the son of David, king of Israel;\n" +
            "\n" +
    ... res of the content goes here

        ));

    }

    private static void addItem(ProverbItem item) {
        ITEMS.add(item);
        ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
    }

    public static class ProverbItem {
        public String id;
        public String content;
        public String chapter;

        public ProverbItem(String id, String content, String chapter) {
            this.id = id;
            this.content = content;
            this.chapter = chapter;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

#### activity_proverb_detail.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/proverb_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProverbDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

#### ProverbDetailActivity

```
public class ProverbDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_proverb_detail);

          getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

          if (savedInstanceState == null) {

              Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
              arguments.putString(ProverbDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                      getIntent().getStringExtra(ProverbDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
              ProverbDetailFragment fragment = new ProverbDetailFragment();
              fragment.setArguments(arguments);
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                      .add(R.id.proverb_detail_container, fragment)
                      .commit();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          int id = item.getItemId();
          if (id == android.R.id.home) {

              NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, ProverbListActivity.class));
              return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }
```

#### strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Proverbs Reference</string>
    <string name="title_proverb_detail">Chapter</string>

</resources>
```

---

I am new to Java and Android development but I am thinking that I have to add an array in **strings.xml** like

```
<string-array name="chapter">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    ....
</string-array>
```

that can be presented after "Chapter" but i am not sure what my next immediate steps should be to link this all up

Comment: where is the code for setting the title of your action bar for detail view?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... this basic way can be used to understand the process...

**On your first activity...**
- Create you ListView and set values..
- Set the Listener Click for your ListView...
- When user select an item, set the number of chapter.
- and that's it!

**On your detail activity...**
- Get the number of chapter...
- Set this number to the titlebar...
- And use that number to load the text of chapter selected...
- And... that's it!
.

**ListChapter.java**

```
public class ListChapters extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    String[] myList = { "Introducing JAVA", "Overview", "Guide: How to...?", "etc" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_chapters);

        myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ); 
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){

                switch(position){
                case 0:
                    OpenChapter(ListChapters.this, ChapterDetail.class, 1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    OpenChapter(ListChapters.this, ChapterDetail.class, 2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    OpenChapter(ListChapters.this, ChapterDetail.class, 3);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    OpenChapter(ListChapters.this, ChapterDetail.class, 4);
                    break;
                }

            };
        });

    }

    public void OpenChapter(Activity activityIn, Class<?> activityOut, int chapter){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activityIn, activityOut);
        Bundle values = new Bundle();
        values.putInt("chapterNum", chapter);
        intent.putExtras(values);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

.
.
**ChapterDetail.java**

```
public class ChapterDetail extends ActionBarActivity {

    int chapterNumber;
    TextView chapterContent;
    String[] chapterText = {
            "This is the content of chapter one, this data comes from db or other source.",
            "This is the content of chapter Two, this data comes from db or other source.",
            "This is the content of chapter Three, this data comes from db or other source.",
            "This is the content of chapter Four, this data comes from db or other source.",
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chapter_detail);

        Bundle values = getIntent().getExtras();
        chapterNumber = values.getInt("chapterNum");

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chapter " + chapterNumber);

        chapterContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chapterContent);

        switch(chapterNumber){
        case 1:
            chapterContent.setText(chapterText[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            chapterContent.setText(chapterText[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            chapterContent.setText(chapterText[2]);
            break;
        case 4:
            chapterContent.setText(chapterText[3]);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct. How can i implement it though, should I just create additional .java files in my content folder?

Comment: On "src" folder -> ListChapter.java, and ChapterDetail.java | On "res/layout" forlder -> chapter_detail.xml, list_chapter.xml | On AndroidManifest.xml, remember add these activities.

Answer (score 0):

When you need handle content from database...
you well need to know about this topics:

- LoadManager.
  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
- AsyncTaskLoader.
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html
- BaseAdapter.
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
- JSON.
  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Some Tutorials:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/

And maybe Callbacks, if you'll use Fragments!
Dificult (for me): http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#implementcallbacks
Easy (I think so): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDHnIZEJ76I

I know... it's crazy all this stuff... but I think that maybe you will need it!